# Override List.ToString() in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a Datagrid where I display Parts. Every Part can have multile identifiers and the Grid looks like this

```
Name Identifiers Size ...
-------------------------
P1    A,B         3
P2    C,D         4
P3    E           2
```

In my Model the Identifiers are stored in a list for every Part

```
class PartListModel {
    public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}
class Part {
    public IList<Identification> Identifications { get; set; }
}
```

but to get it displayed correctly in my View I had to add a Getter to my Part

```
class Part {
    public string IdentNames { 
          get { return string.Join(",", Identifications.Select(i => i.ArticleNumber)); } 
    }
}
```

to display it right in my View

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Identifiers" Binding="{Binding IdentNames}" />
```

That is a hack I like to avoid. How can I make my ViewModel override the `ToString()` method of my List without needing to add that ugly Getter in my Model?

Comment: Personally I'd go with Grant Winney's solution. However, just to give an alternative, you could create your own class that: a) derives from `List<Part>` (less recommended approach) or: b) implements `IList<Part>` and uses a private list for storage (more recommended approach). Then you're free to override `ToString()` the way you see fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option (and you could probably make it more generic to handle varying cases) is to create a value converter to output the desired value:

```
public class MyIdentificationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Join(",", 
            ((List<MainWindowViewModel.Identification>)value).Select(x => x.ArticleNumber));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it in your XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <myWpfApp:MyIdentificationConverter x:Key="MyIdentificationConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

...

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Identifiers" Binding="{Binding Path=Identifications,
                              Converter={StaticResource MyIdentificationConverter}}" />
```

Here's a more generic version, using reflection to find the correct property:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return string.Join(",",
        (((IEnumerable<object>)value).Select(x => x.GetType()
                                     .GetProperty(parameter.ToString()).GetValue(x))));
}
```

And again, calling from XAML: (passing the property to select, as a parameter)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Identifiers" Binding="{Binding Path=Identifications,
                              Converter={StaticResource MyIdentificationConverter},
                              ConverterParameter=ArticleNumber}" />
```

Comment: well it is not generic, because it is just specific to 1 type

Comment: Limitation: the converter works well only with "static" collections. Note that the binding with such converter will not work (i.e. refresh the value) with "dynamic" (for example, `ObservableCollection<T>` class) in case when the collection is changed (item is added/removed).

Answer (score 1):

You can get slightly nicer XAML syntax by writing a markup extension that is itself also a value converter.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(BindingBase))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
public sealed class ConcatenateExtension : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public ConcatenateExtension()
    {
        Separator = ",";
    }

    public ConcatenateExtension(string path)
        : this()
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Separator { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var binding = new Binding(Path);
        binding.Converter = this;
        return binding;
    }

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // 'value' is the property value obtained by binding to `Path`
        // We're assuming here that 'value' can be enumerated
        // Code will obviously throw an exception if it can't

        IEnumerable<object> sequence =
            from object element in value as IEnumerable<object>
            let propertyValue =
                Property == null ?
                    element :
                    element.GetType().GetProperty(Property).GetValue(element)
            select propertyValue;

        return String.Join(Separator, sequence);
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You would use it in the XAML like so:

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:..."

...

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Ids" Binding="{my:Concatenate
    Identifications, Property=ArticleNumber, Separator=' / '}" />
```

The `Separator` property is optional and will default to a single comma.

The code still uses reflection unfortunately but I can't see any way of avoiding that.

Answer (score 0):

i have wrote an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`, you can add it and use it:

```
public static string ToString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values,string seperator,Func<T,string> property)
{
    return string.Join(seperator, values.Select(property));
}
```

and use it like this:

```
List<PhoneDictionary> table = new List<PhoneDictionary>() 
            { 

             new PhoneDictionary { Phone1 = 1, Phone2 =2},
             new PhoneDictionary { Phone1 = 1, Phone2 =2},
             new PhoneDictionary { Phone1 = 2, Phone2 =3},
             new PhoneDictionary { Phone1 = 3, Phone2 =4},
             new PhoneDictionary { Phone1 = 3, Phone2 =4},
            };


 var phones = table.ToString(",",x => x.Phone1.ToString());
```

### Output:

> > 1,1,2,3,3

### My Class:

```
public class PhoneDictionary
{
    public int Phone1 { get; set; }
    public int Phone2 { get; set; }
}
```

In your case you can call this way:

```
string articles = partsViewModel.Parts.ToString(",",x=>x.ArticleNumber);
```

Comment: Thought about that but somewhere I have to tell my View to not take the default ToString() but my implementation.

Comment: yes ofcourse, you have to tell that which property of my class to be returned as comma delimited string

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - I'm not sure that this extension method is particularly well thought out. You effectively save 5 characters as your `phones` example would otherwise be written as `var phones = String.Join(",", table.Select(x => x.Phone1));`. Also your extension method hides the string that separates the elements (i.e. `,`) and you have no way to change it. I think that this is a case where the original code is better.

Comment: @Enigmativity we can add another parameter to pass custom delimiter